# Why do we need T2 = 2T1, and why is there a factor of 2?

Tags: decoherence, spintronics

I am trying to understand why we want T2=2T1. After reading several definitions of T1 and T2, I just got really confused about these two constant. Is there a way (mathematically or visually) to explain why we would need T2 = 2T1?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17690/t-1-t-2-thermal-relaxation-example

Comment: What's your $T_1$ and $T_2$?